# Count Categorical data monthly Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to count categorical data and plot the % of high, med, low for each month.

It should look like this image below:

[image]

I have a data frame with Date and Score which looks like this below

```
-------------------------------
|Date                 | Score  |
|2016-1-02 00:00:00   | High   |
|2016-2-02 00:00:00   | Low    |
|2016-4-23 00:00:00   | Med    |
|2016-5-03 00:00:00   | High   |
|2016-6-02 00:00:00   | High   |
|2016-6-04 00:00:00   | Low    |
|2016-7-02 00:00:00   | Med    |
|2016-12-02 00:00:00  | High   |
-------------------------------
```

I know i can do this to get the split of each one but i dont know how to split this by month and then count each of these

```
 df.groupby('Score').size()

 Score:
 High: 5
 Med: 15
 Low: 155
```

Thank you

Comment: first create a new column for for the month, then group by month and score columns

Comment: I don't know how to plot, but `df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, 'Score']).size()`

Comment: @coldspeed, i think just add a `.plot.bar(stacked=True)`. But I'm not sure about the normalization ^^

Comment: I think, you should convert the score count, to percentage per month

Comment: The `df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, 'Score']).size()` Gives me the right data thank you but sadly .plot.bar(stacked=True) doesn't give me that bar chart. Instead the X axis is (1, High) (1 , Med) (1, Low) (2, High) ... (12, Low)    the number being the month, Y axis comes up as the count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First prepare data

```
In [2056]: dff = (df.set_index('Date').groupby('Score')
                    .resample('MS').count().unstack('Score'))

In [2057]: dff
Out[2057]:
           Score
Score       High  Low  Med
Date
2016-01-01   1.0  NaN  NaN
2016-02-01   0.0  1.0  NaN
2016-03-01   0.0  0.0  NaN
2016-04-01   0.0  0.0  1.0
2016-05-01   1.0  0.0  0.0
2016-06-01   1.0  1.0  0.0
2016-07-01   0.0  NaN  1.0
2016-08-01   0.0  NaN  NaN
2016-09-01   0.0  NaN  NaN
2016-10-01   0.0  NaN  NaN
2016-11-01   0.0  NaN  NaN
2016-12-01   1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Normalize for percentage.

```
In [2058]: dff.div(dff.sum(1), axis=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
Out[2058]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1386ca58>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can remove Multiindex in columns like `dff = (df.set_index('Date').groupby('Score')
                    .resample('MS').count().unstack('Score')['Score'])` - nicer graph without tuples (Score, High)